# Akka actor infinite loop

Tags: scala, akka

I'm trying to write a simple matrix multiplication program with concurrent processing using Scala and Akka actors. I've not even written 10% of the code and I'm running into trouble. I created two actors - master and worker. I'm trying to communicate between them but its runs into an infinite loop. Any suggestions are really appreciated. As you can see, the code below does nothing, it prints 2 10X10 matrices in the master, after that the worker is called. But the worker's workDone message never comes back to the master. I also suspect this has to do something with a warning I'm getting:

patterns after a variable pattern cannot match (inside receive of master for case "masterSend")

```
import akka.actor.{ActorRef, Actor, ActorSystem, Props}

import scala.Array._
import scala.util.Random

case object masterSend
case object workSend
case object workDone


object MatrixMultiply {

  val usage = """
               Usage: MainStart <matrix-dimension> <high-value>
              """

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    if (args.length != 2) {
      println(usage)
      System.exit(1)
    }
    val Dim = args(0).toInt
    val Max = args(1).toInt

    val system = ActorSystem("ComputeSystem")
    val worker = system.actorOf(Props[Worker], name = "worker")
    val master = system.actorOf(Props(new Master(Dim, Max, worker)), name = "master")
    master ! masterSend

  }

  class Master(Dim: Int, Max: Int, worker : ActorRef) extends Actor {
    def receive = {
      case masterSend =>

        val r = new Random(34636)
        val matrixA = ofDim[Int](Dim,Dim)
        val matrixB = ofDim[Int](Dim,Dim)

        println("Matrix A: ")
        for (i <- 0 to Dim - 1) {
          for (j <- 0 to Dim - 1) {
            matrixA(i)(j) = r.nextInt(Max)
            print(matrixA(i)(j) + " ")
          }
          println()
        }

        r.setSeed(23535)
        println("Matrix B: ")
        for (i <- 0 to Dim - 1) {
          for (j <- 0 to Dim - 1) {
            matrixB(i)(j) = r.nextInt(Max)
            print(matrixB(i)(j) + " ")
          }
          println()
        }

        worker ! workSend

      case workDone =>
        println("Work was done!!")
        context.system.shutdown()

    }
  }

  class Worker extends Actor {

    def receive = {
      case workSend =>
        println("Work Done")
        sender ! workDone

    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Any particular reason to use Actors for matrix multiplication?  There's a very good blog post explaining why Futures or parallel collections are a better choice for calculations like matrix mult... https://www.chrisstucchio.com/blog/2013/actors_vs_futures.html

Comment: For example scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray.fill will provide a multi-threaded multi-dimensional array that will calculate maps, filters, etc. in parallel.

Comment: I didn't see your code running into an infinite loop. what is exactly happening?

Comment: @LakshithaRanasingha The master initiates the 2 matrices. After that the worker is sent a message "workSend". The worker receives the message, prints the statement "Work done". But the sender ! workDone line is not working. It never returns to the master, or it returns but doesn't enter workDone  case. And the matrices are printed again and all of these occur infinitely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with pattern matching on objects you've created. It's matching inproperly. Do not bother yourself with objects. Use strings for example:

```
object A {
  val masterSend = "masterSend"
  val workSend = "workSend"
  val workDone = "workDone"
}
object MatrixMultiply {



  val usage = """
               Usage: MainStart <matrix-dimension> <high-value>
              """

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val Dim = 3
    val Max = 2
    val system = ActorSystem("ComputeSystem")
    val worker = system.actorOf(Props[Worker], name = "worker")
    val master = system.actorOf(Props(new Master(Dim, Max, worker)), name = "master")
    master ! A.masterSend

  }

  class Master(Dim: Int, Max: Int, worker : ActorRef) extends Actor {
    def receive = {
      case A.masterSend =>
        println("Master sent")
        worker ! A.workSend
      case A.workDone =>
        println("Work was done!!")
        context.system.shutdown()
    }
  }

  class Worker extends Actor {
    def receive = {
      case A.workSend =>
        println("Work Done")
        sender ! A.workDone

    }
  }

}
```

You've named your object from lower case letter.
`object messageSend`
But pattern matching consider it not as an object but as a some new variable instead.

`case messageSend =>` messageSend - is a variable
You'd be able to write anything here `case magicBall =>` will also compile.

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much. Indeed naming the case objects was the mistake. When I used uppercase for the first letter, it worked fine.

Comment: Also you can use such naming, but in case statement you have to wrap with back quotes   ` `masterSend` `